# How can I constrain property values to keys in the current type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

In typescript, I want to declare an extensible interface via an indexer, to allow additional functions to be associated dynamically, but have sub properties that refer back to those indexed functions by name. Something tells me this may be beyond the acrobatics the TS compiler is capable of, but I've rarely been able to stump it. Any ideas?

```
interface Foo {
  someProp: {
    [x: string]: keyof this; // doesn't work... but something like this to refer to indexed keys?
  };
  [x: string]: Function; // client can provide whatever functions they want in here
}

// usage
let myFoo: Foo = {
   bar: {
      validFuncName: "someFooFunc", // should work
      invalidFuncName: "thisAintNoFunc" // should error!
   },
   someFooFunc: () => {}
}
```

Comment: Not possible without a helper function to do the inferring.

Comment: Can you elaborate on said helper function?

Comment: When I said that this was not possible without a helper function, I knew it was definitely possible but I did not know how difficult it was to get it working. Anyways, I spent a little over 20 minutes on [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyXOJm) snippet here. Unfortunately I am lazy so I did not take the extra mile to make TypeScript report errors on each invalid property separately, but it does report an error if invalid input was given. Because of the "cryptic" nature of TypeScript errors, I have also added a helpful error message in the case of invalid input. Is this sufficient for you?

Comment: Impressive! Your “lazy” 20 minutes is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx36GN) meet your needs? If so, I can write it up as an answer. If not, what criteria are you looking for that it doesn't satisfy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @kelly's answer, here is a slightly less "over engineered" solution.

```
function helper<T extends Record<string, any>>(obj: { 
   [K in keyof T]: K extends "bar" 
     ? Record<string, Exclude<keyof T, "bar">> 
     : Function 
}){}

helper({
   bar: {
      validFuncName: "someFooFunc", // ok
      validFuncName2: "someOtherFunc", // ok
      invalidFuncName: "thisAintNoFunc" // Error
   },
   someFooFunc: () => {},
   someOtherFunc: () => {}
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/FACwpgNgDmBOAUBvYACNAjAhrAXC5ahKAbphAJYAmAYgK4B2AxgHKYC2YeARAM4D2Hanz50mXADQoA9FJR8A1qiIkyVUS3ZgATN34cA8gBdwsdROmyFSouXqkKNBho7dj5HgEFbh5iKdcLFABRWFg+WGsAX3FrPTAhPyY8eABKFABeAD58aNiBMCMTdWS0rJzgSJTgYAAzJ0NyPnoUcGg4AB4AFRQwAA9DMHpKHhQAJTBGcMp2nkNYWwBzSUx6AE9MzPg+dAArPEQUawBtAGkUWxR5MFW+GpROgF08M76BoZGuLFgA6zQAfjGEymMzmi0kQV6jAgtEoYHaVxud06kk+2C4G0Oyjw6gaTUOlUQkSAA)

Comment: Impressive. I did not think TS could infer `T` like that. Well done!

Comment: This community (and typescript) is awesome! That's a clean solution. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of [Tobias S.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73411327/81723) answer (and Kelly's original snippet) that maintains the type of the object passed to the helper function.

```
type ExtractFunctions<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Function ? K : never]: T[K]
}

function helper<
    T extends { 
        [K in keyof T]: K extends "bar"
            ? Record<string, keyof ExtractFunctions<T>>
            : T[K]
    }
>(obj: T): T {
    return obj;
}

helper({
   bar: {
      validFuncName: "someFooFunc", // ok
      validFuncName2: "someOtherFunc", // ok
      invalidFuncName: "thisAintNoFunc" // Error
   },
   someFooFunc: () => {},
   someOtherFunc: () => {}
});
```

Comment: Very useful. I'm awarding the answer to @Tobias S. just because it's simple and satisfies the stated requirements, but the robustness here is great.